# Not able to display sap ui core icon in sap.m table column in ui5

Tags: html, sapui5

I am trying to show coloured icons in one column of sap.m table based on the value in another column.I have used formatter for the same.Below is my view code and formatter code.Pls help.

```
           <items>
                    <ColumnListItem>
                            <cells >
                                <core:Icon src="{path: 'STATUS', formatter: '.formatter.formatIcon'}" color="{path: 'STATUS', formatter: '.formatter.formatIconColor'}" />
                            </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>

                    </items>

  formatter - 


    formatIconColor: function (status) {
    if (status === "Error") {
            return "red";
    } else {
        return "green";
    }
  },
   formatIcon: function (status) {
    return 'sap-icon://circle-task';
    }
```

Comment: looks good. Can you see the icon if you put the values statically into the attributes? Next put a breakpoint in your controllers `onInit()` and verify that  `this.formatter` is the right thing containing both formatter functions. Also you can put a breakpoint into your formatter functions to see if they are called.

Comment: What version of SAPUI5 are you using? I'm not sure, but I believe in older versions icon `circle-task` wasn't available yet